# Using if-then Control Structure, write a script to get the summation of two integers.?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Using if-then Control Structure, write a script to get the summation of two integers. Your script should have:

- the right comment lines, specifying which shell the script should run in, and stating the purpose of the script
- [ ... ] to surround the condition that is to be tested (according to the number of required arguments)
- the variable that hold the result is called sum
- redirect the error with a proper messages that

  ```
            - tell the user how many integers are expected with the proper varliable (s)

            - tell the user how to use the script with the proper varliable (s)
  ```
- use the proper variables for

  ```
            - representing all parameters, as a single string, received from the user

            - representing the number of parameters received from the user

            - representing the name of script
  ```
- exiting from the script with value 2

I tried using sum(($1&$2)) but how to meet the other conditions?

Comment: I don't see any code in your question (except the nonsense `sum(($1&$2))` - what script language is this supposed to be?). Please post what you have so far and explain exactly at which point you are stuck. Also, specify whether you really are writing POSIX shell (as your tags imply), or something else.

Comment: to make a simmple addition, try: `echo $((  1234  +  2345 ))`.